# The const modifier in C

Tags: c

I'm quite often confused when coming back to C by the inability to create an array using the following initialisation pattern...

```
const int SOME_ARRAY_SIZE = 6;
const int myArray[SOME_ARRAY_SIZE];
```

My understanding of the problem is that the const operator does not guarantee const-ness but rather merely asserts that the value pointed to by SOME_ARRAY_SIZE will not change at runtime. But why can the compiler not assume that the value is constant at compile time?  It says 6 right there in the source code...

I think I'm missing something core in my fundamental understanding of C.  Somebody help me out here. :)

[UPDATE]After reading a bit more around C99 and variable length arrays I think I understand this a bit better.  What I was trying to create was a variable length array - const does not create a compile time constant  but rather a runtime constant.  Therfore I was initialising a variable length array, which is only valid in C99 at a function/block scope.  A variable length array at the file scope is impossible as the compiler cannot assign a fixed memory address to an unbounded array.[/UPDATE]

Comment: Please clarify as to whether you're asking about such declarations at local scope or global scope, as the answer is different in each case.

Comment: Sorry, this is a globally scoped declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in C++ the semantics are a bit different. In C++ your code would work fine. You must distinguish between 2 things, `const` and `constant expression`. Const means simply, as you described, that the value is read-only. constant expression, on the other hand, means the value is known compile time and is a compile-time constant. The semantics of const in C are always of the first type. The only constant expressions in C are literals, that's why `#define` is used for such kind of things.

In C++ however, any const object initialized with a constant expression is in itself a constant expression.

I don't know exactly WHY this is so in C, it's just the way it is

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the language syntax demands a integer value between the [ ]. SOME_ARRAY_SIZE is still a variable (even if you told the compiler nobody is allowed to vary it!)

Comment: So is it a deficiency in the implementation of the compiler?  As Paul R commented in his answer the above syntax is now supported by newer versions of gcc...

Comment: I think your compiler is just very picky about how it interprets the C standards.

Answer (score 2):

The `const` keyword is basically a read-only indication. It does not, really, indicate the underlying value will not change, even though that is the case in your example.

When it comes to pointers, this is more clear:

```
void foo(int const * p)
{
  if (*p == 100)
  {
    bar();
    /* Here, the compiler can not assume that *p is 100 */
  }
}
```

In this case, a compiler should not accept the code in your example, as it requires the array size to be constant. If it would accept it, the user could later run into trouble when porting the code a more strict compiler.

Comment: Nice example :)

Seeing another use case for the operator makes things a lot clearer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in C99, and some compilers prior to C99 also had support for this as an extension to C89 (e.g. gcc). If you're stuck with an old compiler that doesn't have C99 support though (e.g. MSVC) then you'll have to do it the *old skool* way and use a `#define` for the array size.

Note that that above comments apply only to such declarations at local scope (i.e. automatic variables). C99 still doesn't allow such declarations at global scope.

Comment: Nope, C99 does not support it either. C++ does, however.

Comment: @Lindydancer: OK - to clarify - C99 allows this within local scope (i.e. with automatic variables) but not at global scope - I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: The EDG C99 front-end issues an error for: `void foo(void) { const int X = 6; const int myArray[X] = {100}; bar(myArray); }`. However, I might be wrong so please post a counter example, or a reference to the C99 standard.

Comment: @Lindydancer: The relevant part is §6.7.5.2 Array Declarators.  Eg. *If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.*

Comment: @Lindydancer: gcc 4.x (`gcc -std=c99 -Wall -strict -pedantic`) and Intel's ICC 11.x (`icc -std=c99 -Wall`) compile this without any complaint (other than an unused variable warning), as does IBM's xlc. The only compiler that I know of that won't compile this is MSVC, since it doesn't support C99 or GNU extensions to C89/C90.

Comment: @caf: You're right! I had **variable length arrays** turned off by default. However, I interpreted the question so that the expression should be seen as constant in local scope, which isn't the really the case here... Having said that, **variable length arrays** is not something that you typically want to use, as they are complicate to implement (often done by using `malloc` under the hood), and are not `setjmp` `longjmp`-savvy.

Comment: @Lindydancer: Well, personally I put `setjmp` and `longjmp` firmly in the "not something you'd typically want to use" category themselves ;).  VLAs are more typically implemented on the stack, requiring the use of a frame pointer (but I do agree that they'd not particularly useful in most cases).

Comment: @caf: If VLA:s are implemented to store things on the stack, they are less evil. However, I've seen cases where they are implemented using simple calls to `malloc` and `free`, leading to much longer allocation times, risk of defragementation, etc. Personally, I would never trust them, unless I know exactly how they are implemented, and I know the code will never be ported. However, I've seen them being used in high-performance systems like a virtual machines designed to be portable, so I will continue singing the dont-use-VLA-blues. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

i just did a very quick test with my Xcode and Objective C file I currently had open on my machine and put this in the .m file:

```
const int arrs = 6;
const int arr[arrs];
```

This compiles without any issues.